# Goood books for arithmetic topology

Tags: arithmetic, book-recommendation

I'm looking for good books to start studying arithmetic topology, but the material seen very hard to find online.
In fact I could only find one book [Knots and Primes: An Introduction to Arithmetic Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447121570)

Comment: It looks like that is literally THE book on Arithmetic Topology. I have to admit, it's not a subarea I've ever heard mentioned before.

Comment: Relevant [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244951/applications-of-arithmetic-topology-to-number-theory)